# Regular Expression to find a string between brackets and quotes

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm having a problem parsing the message i get from the server. This is the message:

```
{"":["Current Password is invalid."]}
```

What I'm trying to do is to show Current Password is invalid in a Toast, parsing it with regex. So far I got:

```
^(\\:\\[\\\"(.*?)\\\"\\]?
```

but it doesn't really work. Any suggestions how to fix the regex? Keep in mind that the first quotes (before the ":") might not be always empty.

Comment: Your input looks like Json so it might be better to use a Json parser.

Comment: I see you are using a `?` quantifier with `]`. Perhaps, all you need is `":\\[\"([^\"]+)"` and use `matcher.find()` to access `group(1)` value. See http://ideone.com/9M5W0r.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried that, but it returned an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll()` will work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "{\"\":[\"Current Password is invalid.\"]}";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll(".*?\\[\"(.*?)\"\\].*", "$1"));
    //  ^^ Extract text between "[" and "] and replace the entire string with it.
}
```

O/P :

```
Current Password is invalid.
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you.